# how to do a pagination-django with variable 'per_page'?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-pagination

how to do a pagination with variable 'per_page'.
For example, I have 100 articles I wish that the first page (1) contains 3 articles, the second page (2) contains 5 articles, will excite, me who draws of how many articles in each page.
see the picture.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have same problem, I can't search good answer from google, but I have a trick solution.

If `per_page` is constant like 5, my code in view is:

```
paginator = Paginator(articles, 5)

for page_no in paginator.page_range:
  context_data = {
    'paginator': paginator,
    'page_no': page_no,
  }
```

My solution is that create fake Paginator instance for every forloop, if per_page is variable and collected in num_articles_page list:

```
page_no = 0
row_counter = 0

for row_num in num_articles_page:
  # count page_no for forloop
  page_no = page_no + 1

  # articles list in this page
  this_page_list = article_list[row_counter:]

  # count row for forloop
  row_counter = row_counter + row_num

  # push some fake item before this_page_list
  this_page_list = [None]*(page_no-1)*row_num + this_page_list

  # create Paginator instance in every forloop
  paginator = Paginator(this_page_list, row_num)

  if paginator.num_pages < page_no:
    break

  context_data = {
    'paginator': paginator,
    'page_no': page_no,
    'this_page': paginator.page(page_no),
  }
```

so `this_page` will be correct in every `page_no`, you can use method like `this_page.has_next()` or `this_page. has_other_pages()`

in template can also use:

```
{% for this_article in paginator|page:page_no %}
{% endfor %}

{% if this_page. has_previous == False %}
{% endif %}
```